# How can I load data from a CKAN API into a recline.js generated map on an external site?

Tags: jquery, ckan

I'd like to get data served from a CKAN API and serve it up as a recline.js generated map.

It appears that the code below is successfully able to GET data out of the CKAN db but the recline.js doesn't generate a layer of points from the data despite that there are longitude and latitude fields.

Links to live examples and to all the code can be found here:
http://theplaceisnow.aedileworks.com/2014/08/28/70-stuck-on-how-to-get-ckan-data-into-a-recline-js-generated-map/

```
<body>
    <div id="mymap"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
          resource_id: '5f693113-9e38-4395-a2b2-2f2ebbe87f10', // the resource id
          limit: 50, // get 50 results
          q: 'bus' // query for 'bus'
        };
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://odwe.ca/api/action/datastore_search',
          data: data,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total);
            }
          });
        var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset({
          records: data
        });
        var $el = $('#mymap');
        var map = new recline.View.Map({
           model: dataset
        });
        $el.append(map.el);
          map.render();
   </script>
</body>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alan P from Twitter, I was able to find the answer to the problem at hand. https://twitter.com/alanpca/status/505078976319356928

In short, the mapping script has to be placed with the success function, and that the variable dataset needs to contain not **records.data** but **records: data.result.records**

Much thanks to Alan!